# firstDuplicate question on CodeSignal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, testcase

I couldn't figure out why I passed 22/23 on this challenge and not able to solve the last test case since it was hidden.. The feedback from the CodeSignal is

> Tests passed: 22/23. Execution time limit exceeded: Program exceeded
> the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a
> few seconds for any possible input.

**Challenge**
Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length, find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other number does. If there are no such elements, return -1.

**Example**

For a = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2], the output should be solution(a) = 3.

There are 2 duplicates: numbers 2 and 3. The second occurrence of 3 has a smaller index than the second occurrence of 2 does, so the answer is 3.

For a = [2, 2], the output should be solution(a) = 2;
For a = [2, 4, 3, 5, 1], the output should be solution(a) = -1.

**Input/Output**

[execution time limit] 4 seconds (js)

[input] array.integer a

Guaranteed constraints:
1 ≤ a.length ≤ 105,
1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length.

[output] integer

The element in a that occurs in the array more than once and has the minimal index for its second occurrence. If there are no such elements, return -1.

**My code**

```
function solution(a) {
  let first = Infinity
  for ( let i = 0; i<a.length; i++ ) {
      let pointer = i+1;
      while (pointer <a.length) {
          if (a[i] === a[pointer] && pointer<first) {
              first = pointer;
          } 
          pointer +=1
      }
  } 
  if (first === Infinity) {
      return -1
  }
  return a[first]
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bad cases, you're iterating over the whole array for every element in it - `O(n ^ 2)`. The inner `while(pointer < a.length)` results in the argument taking too much time.

Instead, make a Set of elements found so far, and return when the first duplicate element is found (which will be the minimal second index).

```
const solution = (a) => {
  const set = new Set();
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (set.has(item)) return item;
    set.add(item);
  }
  return -1;
};
```

Since this has no nested loop (`.has` and `.add` is `O(1)`), this is `O(n)` overall, which should be quick enough.

Comment: Awesome solution. However time limit is 4 seconds, and the original code has O(n^2), how's that slow or taking too much time? the constraint is only 105 in length.

Comment: Either the said constraint is not accurate, and they have larger arrays, or the CPU allocated to run a test is extraordinarily terrible, I guess.